# How can i fix 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia' for Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

I am using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia in my javascript to call webcam. it is working for chrome but not for safari.
I know, navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is not supported for safari.

But, Is there any way to fix this issue for safari?

Thanks,
Naresh.

Comment: Maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/42221646/378979

Answer (score 1):

As Safari 10 doesn't have support for WebRTC, so navigator.getUserMedia will not have any effect. Safari 11+ has support for WebRTC hence you can use navigator.getUserMedia by enabling 'Enable Legacy WebRTC API' on develop menu or navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia.

Comment: In Safari v12.1.2 I see `Enable Legacy WebRTC API` in `Develop` menu but it is inactive/disabled (grayed out). How to enable it please?

Answer (score 0):

This is only supported in Safari 11: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

You might be able to use navigator.getUserMedia (which is deprecated so be careful here): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia